# Unity. 2D. Слежение за игроком по горизонтали

Tags: c#, unity3d, камера, 2d

Помогите переписать код:
1.Чтобы камера следила за игроком только по x (горизонталь)
2. В реальном времени (без плавности (задержек) )
3. Чтобы z оставался -10, тк без этого камера показывает только синий фон
4. не обязательно, но всё же, мне кажется переменные названы как то тупо, какие лучше дать имена?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform player;
    Vector3 playerVector;

    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        playerVector = player.position;
        playerVector.x = -3.5f;  
        playerVector.z = -10;      
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, playerVector, Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кажется вы не понимаете что делает метод `Vector3.Lerp`. Он возвращает значение между позициями `a` и `b`, а третий аргумент `t` это процент пути в диапазоне от 0.0 до 1.0. Использовать `Time.deltaTime` как `t` не имеет никокого смысла.

```
transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x, transform.position.y, -10);
```